# Logger provider: How can I implement a custom formatter

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

I implemented a custom logger provider. My custom logger has this signature:

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, 
    TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
```

How is `formatter` being passed?

And how can I implement a custom `formatter`? Say, if I want it to be formatting everything in JSON

I'm new to Net Core and I don't fully understand how this works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter` function that is being passed to your function is basically just a utility function to convert the state into a single string message. Inside your logger, you are basically just expected to call `formatter(state, exception)` to get the formatted message that should be logged.

Usually, you do not really need to care about the function, other than calling it to get the formatted message, so that’s what all loggers usually do. For the purpose of a JSON logger, you could just ignore it completely, or at least also export the formatted message so it’s there as a readable string.

A quick and dirty JSON logger’s `Log` method could actually look like this:

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
{
    var jsonLine = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
        logLevel,
        eventId,
        parameters = (state as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)?.ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value),
        message = formatter(state, exception),
        exception = exception?.GetType().Name
    });

    // store the JSON log message somewhere
    Console.WriteLine(jsonLine);
}
```

As you can see, it’s not that much magic to generate the JSON object here.

Comment: Actually, you _shouldn't_ pass the `exception` parameter, because the default formatter completely ignores it. See https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/442.

Comment: @Métoule If the default formatter ignores it, I don’t get why this would mean that you *should not* pass it. It is ignored, so it doesn’t matter whether you pass it or not. And passing it anyway makes it consistent with all other loggers.

Comment: OK, shouldn't was a bit strong, but I banged my head on the wall for so long because I couldn't understand why the exception didn't appear in my logs. Not passing the exception to the formatter makes it clear that it doesn't handle it, so there's no confusion.

Comment: That cast is godsend! (state as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)

Answer (score -5):

First, this doesn't really have anything to do with .NET Core. It looks like you're using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, which is just a generic logging facade that you can use pretty much anywhere, .NET Core app or not. It just happens to be the default used by ASP.NET Core apps; that's all.

Second, if you don't know how to implement this method, it may not be a good idea to be creating your own logging provider. What is it that you're trying to do that there's not already an existing adapter for?

That said, the `Func<TState, Exception, string>` type means that it needs a function that accepts a parameter of type `TState` and one of type `Exception` and returns a string. Essentially:

```
public string MyFormatter<TState>(TState state, Exception exception)
{
    // create some string
    return someString;
}
```

Or, it could be implemented via a lambda:

```
(state, exception) => exception?.Message ?? state.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm trying to format my logs in a certain way. Including formatting the state in a specific json format. The adapters I've seen work but like I said I'm trying to follow a specific format for the logs.
Does this mean I have to pass a formatter every time I call logmessage? Is there a way to inject a default formatter in my iLoger?